# Angular Pipe - Sort Numbers

Tags: angular, sorting, pipe

Trying really hard to figure out how to sort numbers. I'm dealing with an ngFor loop and I'd like to sort some of my values. I'm using timecode (film / TV) numbers without colons. Numbers like

01002000
01003000
01000012

I'd like to sort these in asc order using a pipe. For the life of me, I can't seem to get it to work

I've created a pipe and I'm trying

```
export class SortTimecodePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, direcion): any {

    return value.sort();
  }
}
```

Im also aware that sort deals with strings, so I've also tried handing the sort function a parameter.

```
export class SortTimecodePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, direcion): any {
    function compare(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    }

    return value.sort(compare);
  }
}
```

None of these options work. The sorting isn't happening.

Can you provide any help?

------- EDIT -------

The data that comes back is actually an array of objects, they look like this

```
[
{"timecodeIn": 01000020, "timecodeOut": 01000010, "Reason": "Alt Line", "Line": "Hey there"},
{"timecodeIn": 01000005, "timecodeOut": 01000007, "Reason": "Extra", "Line": "You"}
]

I'm tyring to ngFor this array of objects, sorted by the 'timecodeIn' property.

Thanks for the note on sorting numbers like this over strings, I can see how it would fail now. Also, wondering if sorting in the component is better than the view (pipe)
```

Comment: you can use array of numbers after sorting it down no. according to my understanding no need to use pipe in you case. anyway if you can add your question in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-46ccps

Comment: Javascript treats as octal representation if any number starts with 0. In your case all (started with 0) so it treats as octal and converts it into decimal. So In order to avoid this convert timecodes directly to strings '0110022'. Then directly apply sort function.

Comment: Mike,take into consideration what @PALLAMOLLASAI has said. Also, if possible share the end sorted results. To get fastest solution, try adding a stackblitz.com demo code

Comment: make a stackblize example To get solution fast, Please ; https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check the [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipes-btw5jw?file=app/app.component.ts). Maybe you have a typo or some other problem but considering we are talking about strings:

```
numbersStr = ['01002000', '01003000', '01000012'];
```

or numbers

```
numbers = [1002000, 1003000, 1000012];
```

Then in the html

```
<div>
  <h4> Sorting strings array </h4>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let number of numbersStr | sortStringsPipe">{{number}}</li>
  </ul>
  <h4> Sorting number array </h4>
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let number of numbers | sortPipe"> 
       {{number}}</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

The following filter works perfectly.

```
import {PipeTransform,Pipe} from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({
  name:'sortStringsPipe',
  pure:false
})
export class ShortStringsPipe implements PipeTransform {


transform(value:any[]):any{
  return value.sort();
}

}
```